# String concatenation of algebric term

Tags: php, string

I would like to add two integers and concatenate their result to a string, that is:

Add 1 to `$i`, and concatenate that result to the string `'icon'`. I thought the following syntax would work:

```
$x = 'icon'.$i+1;
```

However it doesn't do what I want - it keeps returning the value `'icon1'`, disregarding the value of `$i`.

What's the right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$i = 0; // init $i
$x = 'icon'.($i+1);
```

If you want to regularly increment `$i` variable:

```
$x = 'icon'.(++$i);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$temp = $i+1;
$x = 'icon'.$temp;
```

You are getting wrong answer because of "Operator Precedence",

Ref this link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Here see the line : `left   + - .   arithmetic and string`

`.` has more Precedence than `+`, So your expression will be like : `$x = ('icon'.$i)+1;`

To solve it either use the method i mentioned above or hsz answer

ie : `$x = 'icon'.($i+1);`

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that, but I want to avoid unnecessary lines of code. If this is something that can be done in one line, then I prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) explains why this is happening.

You can use brackets:

```
$x = 'icon'.($i+1);
```

This should do the job.

My test:

```
$i = 18;
$x = 'icon'.($i+1);
var_dump($x);

--> string(6) "icon19"
```